# NSMutableData appendData: gets reallocated, memory issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ipad, memory-management

I added a progress bar on my application. everything is fine, running the way I want them. but the problem is when I append the downloaded data in didReceivedData: , my responseData is getting reallocated and thus makes my application consume too much memory. then crash after receivedMemoryWarning.

```
   -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
      {
         //response data is getting reallocated with bigger size of data
         [responseData appendData:data];
         NSNumber* curLength = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[responseData length] ];
         float progress = [curLength floatValue] / [filesize floatValue] ;
         progressView.progress = progress;
     }
```

Can someone here help me how to get rid of reallocation in my responseData?

thanks!!!

Comment: You aren't showing the code where your responseData is being created/reallocated. Show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating `responseData`, use `initWithCapacity:` to give it a hint how many bytes you will require (the expected content length can possibly be retrieved from the response header).